# Hide products category disabled

Tags: magento2, product, products

I have disabled a category of products that are only for Christmas, but if I use the search engine, the products appear although the category is disabled. How can I do so that the products are also hidden? Do I have to disable the products one by one?

Comment: disabling a category does not disables associated product. You will have to disable them one by one or you can write a small script to do this or you can simply select those products using mass action in order grid and change the status to disabled

Answer (score 0):

Make an observer on the `catalog_category_save_after` event for the adminhtml. In the observer you can retrieve the category object and write your logic there. In general;

- Create Event
- Retrieve category that is saved in observer.
- Retrieve all products from this category and based on the status of the category you can loop through these products to set them enabled/disabled.

If you don't know how to create an event:

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-create-events.html